# ¿Más de un return en una función?

Tags: c

¿Es considerado buena práctica el usar más de una instrucción `return` dentro de la función? por ejemplo:

```
if ( /* ... */ )
  return x;
else
  return y;
```

o tengo que crear una variable auxiliar para hacer solamente un return al final del código con esa variable auxiliar?

Comment: Depende de lo que realmente necesites... Cuando `return` no devuelve punteros, devuelve códigos de error dependiendo de la función, así que la pregunta real es ¿Cuando es necesario utilizar más de un `return`?

Comment: Es considerado una mala practica, aunque de pende mucho de lo que estés haciendo, algunas veces no hay de otra que hacerlo, pero en el resto de los casos hay que evitarlo, se vuelve mas sencillo leer el código y hacerle seguimiento a el cuando posee uno o pocos `return`.

Comment: una funcion solo debe tener una meta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No existe una política unificada sobre este tema. Cada solución tiene sus ventajas y sus inconvenientes:

**un único return**

Esta solución suele facilitar el mantenimiento de las funciones, ya que para cualquier función conocerás tanto su punto de entrada (al inicio de la función) como su punto de salida (al final de la misma).

Por el motivo anterior verás que es más facil depurar el código ya que para verificar lo devuelto por una función requerirá un único punto de parada.

**varios return**

Esta solución se puede utilizar para evitar un anidamiento excesivo en la función:

```
void variosReturnFunc()
{
  if( !condicion1 )
    return;

  // ...

  if( !condicion2 )
    return;

  // ...
}

void unReturnFunc()
{
  if( condicion1 )
  {
    // ...

    if( condicion2 )
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Es facil ver en el ejemplo anterior que si el número de condiciones es relativamente elevado (más de 3 por ejemplo) el excesivo número de llaves anidadas puede dificultar la legibilidad del códigio.

Su principal desventaja es que que depurar una función requiere localizar todos los `return`.

**Conclusión personal**

Como norma general intenta programar las funciones con un único `return`. Si junto con este hábito te acostumbras a no escribir funciones excesivamente largas (más de 30 líneas) tanto mejor.

Yo acostumbro a dejar la opición de varios `return` en aquellas funciones en las que se efectuan una serie de chequeos iniciales para no llenar de llaves la función. Considero que en este caso está justificado el uso de varios puntos de salida ya que con ello se mejora la legibilidad del código... sin embargo remarco que es mi opinión personal.